# Collecting the third value in a list of arrray-type strings using Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of values on a web page that I would like to collect the third value (Value 3)

```
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
```

I can cycle through the lines using JQuery .each(), but getting the third value means writing some convoluted global replace code, but there must be an efficient, simpler way of doing this?

Any guidance very welcome!

Comment: I'd like to collect the third values as either an array or even better a jquery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string by comma and use the third element in the result.

`str.split(',')[2]`

Comment: suggest trimming it too

Comment: Bang! That was the efficient solution I was sure was out there - thank you @shriharsha-kl

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method.

```js
var res = $('p') // get all the p tags
  // iterate over the collection to generate string collection
  .map(function() {
    return $(this)
      // get text content
      .text()
      // split by , 
      .split(',')
      // get the last element from split result
      .pop()
      // trim out whitespace
      .trim();

    // get the result as an array from jQuery collection
  }).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
```

---

With pure Javascript :

```js
var res =
  // get all p tags and then covert into array
  // for older browser use [].slice.call(....)
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('p'))
  // iterate over the array to generate string array
  .map(function(ele) {
    return ele
      // get text content
      .textContent
      // split by , 
      .split(',')
      // get the last element from split result
      .pop()
      // trim out whitespace
      .trim();
  });

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
<p>Value 1, Value 2, Value 3</p>
```

Comment: Thank you @pranav-c-balan! I have learned much from your answer, and really appreciate it.